# How mysql binlog position generate?

Tags: mysql

The binlog position isn't continuous, so how mysql binlog position generate?

There no document about this.

Comment: More details, please.  Where are you getting the position from?  Are you expecting _consecutive_ numbers?  Monotonically increasing?  What?

Comment: @RickJames No ,  I just want to know how mysql compute the pos ?

Comment: @shaoyihe, did you figure it out? I have the same question.

Comment: There is some related information at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_start-position & https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_stop-position

Answer (score 1):

The binlog position is the byte offset into the current binlog.  So, the pair of binlog filename and pos uniquely identify the location in the virtually unlimited binlog.

The GTID (if being used) also provides a unique location, but it is not "offset" based.